# C - Ncurses window not displaying

Tags: c, ncurses

My cursor movements are working as expected, the only problem is my window is just not showing up. What i have written to appear in the window is not showing. I tried googling the solution but similar code does it the same way I have. I just don't see what is the issue here.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that, my actual intention for this window is to have an updating score for a game. The print that u see there is just an example.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int oldy = 0;
    int oldx = 0;
    char m = 'l';
    initscr();
    WINDOW* win;
    win = newwin(1, 40, 10 ,0);
    mvwprintw(win,0,0,"First line");
    wrefresh(win);

    while(m != 'q')
    {
            m=getch();
    if(m == 's')
        {
            move((y= oldy+1),x);
            refresh();
            oldy = y;
        }
    else if(m == 'd')
        {
            move(y,(x=oldx+1));
            refresh();
            oldx = x;
        }
    else if(m == 'a')
        {
            move(y,(x=oldx-1));
            refresh();
            oldx = x;
        }
    else if(m == 'w')
        {
            move((y= oldy-1),x);
            refresh();
            oldy = y;
        }
    else 
        m = 'q';
    }

    delwin(win);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like follows,

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int y = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int oldy = 0;
        int oldx = 0;
        char m = 'l';
        initscr();

        mvaddstr(0,0, "First line");

        while(m != 'q')
        {
                m=getch();
                if(m == 's')
                {
                        move((y= oldy+1),x);
                        refresh();
                        oldy = y;
                }
                ................
                ................
```

Comment: But then the window is totally removed right? I want the window to be there. The problem im having is that the window is not displaying. The purpose of the window is so that i can display a changing score. The "first line" was just an example print.

Comment: win = initscr(); other than creating a new window